# setItem in AsyncStorage doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm trying to upload some data to the server from React Native. The data is stored in AsyncStorage.

The data is as follows :

```
let vehicles = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "make_text": "Peugeot",
    "model_text": "208",
    "color_text": "Argent",
    "category_text": "CT",
    "tag_text": "",
    "vin": "123456",
    "registration": "",
    "reference": "",
    "comment": "",
    "autralis_id": 151390
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "make_text": "Peugeot",
    "model_text": "307",
    "color_text": "Bleu",
    "category_text": "CT",
    "tag_text": "",
    "vin": "654321",
    "registration": "",
    "reference": "",
    "comment": "",
    "autralis_id": 156413
  }
]
```

And

```
let vehicle_slots = [
  {
    "vehicle_id": 1,
    "slot_id": 118,
    "area": "",
    "zone": "B",
    "aisle": "",
    "side": "S",
    "col": 2,
    "level": 0,
    "position": 0,
    "timestamp": "201705021544",
    "picturepath": "",
    "pictureguid": "0a016bb9-b7bb-4dd7-a0bf-407ef31a0c1a",
    "reason": "ENTER",
    "handled": 0,
    "uploaded": 0
  },
  {
    "vehicle_id": 1,
    "slot_id": 2521,
    "area": "",
    "zone": "C",
    "aisle": "",
    "side": "E",
    "col": 4,
    "level": 0,
    "position": 0,
    "timestamp": "201705021544",
    "picturepath": "",
    "pictureguid": "64c726e2-37ec-4ab7-8b57-b08e9899086a",
    "reason": "ENTER",
    "handled": 0,
    "uploaded": 0
  }
]
```

I want to send only those which have `uploaded` and `handled` property equals to **0**.

Thus, first I get those values where `uploaded` and `handled` property is equal to 0. I do it as follows:

```
try {
  let vehicle_data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('vehicle');
  if (vehicle_data !== null){
    // We have data!!
    let vehicle_slot_data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('vehicle_slot');
    if (vehicle_slot_data !== null){
      vehicle_data = JSON.parse(vehicle_data);
      vehicle_slot_data = JSON.parse(vehicle_slot_data);

      let result_to_handle = [];
      let result_to_upload = [];

      vehicle_slot_data.forEach(v => {
        let not_handled = vehicle_data.find(m => m.id === v.vehicle_id && v.handled === 0);
        let not_uploaded = vehicle_data.find(m => m.id === v.vehicle_id && v.uploaded === 0);

        if ( not_uploaded ) result_to_upload.push(that.renderData(v, not_uploaded)[0]);
        if ( not_handled ) result_to_handle.push(that.renderData(v, not_handled)[0]);

      });

      //Here I have result_to_handle and result_to_upload with the data that I need to send to the server.

      ............
```

If `result_to_handle` and `result_to_upload` have `length > 0` then I want to send them to the server and update the property `handled` and property `uploaded` to **1** in AsyncStorage.

I try to do it as follows :

```
..............

if (result_to_handle.length > 0){
  let options = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(result_to_handle),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  };
  fetch(data_url + "/manager/transport/sync/movements/", options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseData => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('vehicle_slot')
      .then(json => {
      let data = [];
      if (json) data = JSON.parse(json);
      let result = [];
      forEach(data, value => {
        if( value.handled === 0 ){
          value.handled = 1;
          result.push(value);
        }else{
          result.push(value);
        }
      });

      AsyncStorage.setItem('vehicle_slot', JSON.stringify(result))
    });
  });
}

if (result_to_upload.length > 0){
  forEach(result_to_upload, value => {
    if (value.picturepath) {
      let body = new FormData();
      const photo = {
        uri: value.picturepath,
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        name: value.pictureguid + '.jpg',
      };
      body.append('image', photo);
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', data_url + "/manager/transport/sync/picture/?pictureguid=" + value.pictureguid);
      xhr.onload = (e) => {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {

            AsyncStorage.getItem('vehicle_slot')
              .then(json => {
              if (json){
                let data = JSON.parse(json);
                let result_data = [];
                forEach(data, val => {
                  if( val.pictureguid === value.pictureguid ){
                    val.uploaded = 1;
                    result_data.push(val);
                  }else{
                    result_data.push(val);
                  }
                });
                AsyncStorage.setItem('vehicle_slot', JSON.stringify(result_data), () => s_cb())
              }
            });

          }
        }
      };
      xhr.onerror =  (e) => console.log('Error');
      xhr.send(body);
    } else {
      AsyncStorage.getItem('vehicle_slot')
        .then(json => {
        if (json){
          let data = JSON.parse(json);
          let result_data = [];
          forEach(data, val => {
            if( val.pictureguid === value.pictureguid ){
              val.uploaded = 1;
              result_data.push(val);
            }else{
              result_data.push(val);
            }
          });
          AsyncStorage.setItem('vehicle_slot', JSON.stringify(result_data), () => s_cb())
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

But the result that I get is not correct.

The `vehicle_slot` from AsyncStorage is as follows:

```
[
  {
    "vehicle_id": 1,
    "slot_id": 118,
    "area": "",
    "zone": "B",
    "aisle": "",
    "side": "S",
    "col": 2,
    "level": 0,
    "position": 0,
    "timestamp": "201705021544",
    "picturepath": "",
    "pictureguid": "0a016bb9-b7bb-4dd7-a0bf-407ef31a0c1a",
    "reason": "ENTER",
    "handled": 1,
    "uploaded": 0
  },
  {
    "vehicle_id": 1,
    "slot_id": 2521,
    "area": "",
    "zone": "C",
    "aisle": "",
    "side": "E",
    "col": 4,
    "level": 0,
    "position": 0,
    "timestamp": "201705021544",
    "picturepath": "",
    "pictureguid": "64c726e2-37ec-4ab7-8b57-b08e9899086a",
    "reason": "ENTER",
    "handled": 1,
    "uploaded": 1
  }
]
```

Thus, for the first object is the value `uploaded` still equal to 0 but it should be equal to 1.

Any advice?

Comment: What a wall of text. You should really try reducing your code to just the essential parts. For instance, if all you care about in your `vehicle` JSON object are the `handled` and `uploaded` fields, there is no reason to provide the entire structure, and it makes your question terrible to read.

Comment: Please give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page a read.

Comment: @Pedro Castilho I could do that but I wanted to explain it as best as possible.

Comment: The issue is that including parts of your code which are not involved in the problem only makes reading your question harder for people who want to help, and it does not make your explanation better.

Comment: @Pedro Castilho Alright. I'm going to edit my question.

Comment: Also, there are way too many failure points in your implementation for a straight answer. For instance, you might just be getting `uploaded = 0` because there is something wrong with the `pictureguid` field. You should probably eliminate those failure points as possible reasons.

Comment: I'm sorry if it seems like I'm just being an asshole for the sake of it, I'm not. I want to help, but at the moment there's just too much that might go wrong for me to even be sure about where to look for issues.

Comment: @Pedro Castilho No problem. ;-) , can you see this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43741606/react-native-setitem-in-storage